# How can I create a React Js Layouts

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help me with create ReactJs Horizontal and Vertical layout component.

It would be great if you can provide example or tutorial.

Comment: React doesn't care - Try to find out how to do a horizontal or vertical layout in HTML and then just do the same in React (If you are talking about React Native its another answer, re-tag the question if that's the case)

Comment: I am taking about react not react native. I though is there any component library or some example.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking by "layout component". Find some examples of what you mean in existing CSS frameworks, then edit the question to explain why you're having problems using them with React.

Answer (score 0):

I found useful npm repository.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-layout-pane